# Feed GPG with answers

Tags: bash, gpg

I wish to do something like:

```
echo -e "trust\n5" | gpg --edit-key "Dor"
```

In order to supply GPG with answers that were made in advance.

But it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: I think an easier solution with `gpg --export-ownertrust` and `gpg --import-ownertrust` may be possible here, instead of trying to automate `gpg --edit-key`.

Comment: Unattended Usage of GPG: http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html

Comment: You could probably also do something like `gpg --edit-key "Dor" <<<"trust"`? This is using a HERESTRING.

Comment: There is also the `--batch` and `--yes` switches to `gpg`, they look like smoking guns to me.

Comment: 2 more leads that have working examples: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/automated-gpg-key-trust-877040/ & http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gnupg/users/51413.

Comment: I'd write this up but do not have time today, if anyone wants to take the above and construct an answer with it have at it (looking to you Martin 8-))!!!

Comment: @sim: `--batch` doesn't work. Eventually I used `--import-ownertrust` with a little string manipulation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo -e "trust\n5" | gpg --edit-key "Dor"` doesn't work because `gpg` does not read the answers from `stdin`, but opens `/dev/tty` directly for reading.

This can be worked around with [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/), a tool for automating interactive applications.

Comment: Thanks but `expect` seems too complicated for the task. Is it possible to write to `/dev/tty`? How can I tell which file exactly the `gpg` process has opened?

Comment: @Dor `expect` is exactly the tool you need to, in effect, write to `/dev/tty`.

Comment: I accept your answer since you gave it first. I'll read about `expect` thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas Nyman answered, the solution is to use `expect` or similar tool.

Unfortunately, `expect` can be difficult to learn and use, and it's a significant investment in time and effort to learn a language that's usable for only one task.  You may find it easier - and more useful in the long run - to use Perl or Python, both of which have libraries that can be used to do the same thing as `expect`.

For perl, that would be [Expect.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect/)

For Python, take a look at [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect)

Both of these are probably already packaged for your linux distribution - e.g. in debian, they are `libexpect-perl` and `python-pexpect`.

BTW, while it's not specifically relevant to your question it is worth noting that Perl also has libraries/modules designed specifically for doing `expect`-like things over network connections - e.g. perl's `Net::SSH` and `Net::Telnet` modules.  Python has similar libraries.

Comment: +1 for the additional info! I lean towards the python library.